# Is it possible to make changes on specific page with JSPDF?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf

I want a specific page to show different text and other pages to show same text for that i have used the following login but its overlapping.

```
doc.setPage(1);
doc.setPage(3);
doc.text(..........);
doc.setPage(2);
doc.text(.......);
```

The text is coming different on page 2 but the issue is that text of page 2 is also overlapping with page 1 and 3. One more way is that to change the order of pages but i don't want to do it.
Is there any way to define specific page using JSPDF?

Comment: What values do you pass to `doc.text()` for X and Y?

Comment: Same values for x and y because i want it on same position but different text. The values are. doc.text('Hello',240,95) etc.

Comment: Have you tried first `.addPage()` x3, so you have 3 blank pages, and then do `setPage(1)`, so that indexes already be set to proper pages, and then you just jump between empty pages